# El pseudoelemento ::after no me deja posicionar

Tags: html, css

primero que tal!.
Ahora si, tengo un problema, yo tengo un contenedor llamado "panel-lateralIzquierdo", este panel contiene dos divs. Bien, como ven en mi css aplico en "operar-tareas" un ::after como pseudoelemento, esto solo para crear como una barra horizontal en la parte inferior de mi contenedor, tambien uso el ::before para hacer lo mismo pero en la parte superior.

El asunto esta en que, cuando ya tengo creado el ::after, empiezo a asignar los atributos a mi elemento div "cambiar-operacion" pero ya cuando le doy dimensiones, este toma su forma pero **queda atrapado en el ::after**. Es decir, al darle alto y ancho a mi segundo div "cambiar-operacion" que se supone debe quedar debajo del primero "panel-lateralIzquierdo", este queda debajo del div primero pero no por debajo del ::after, o sea, queda atrapado entre el div del panel y el ::after de este panel. No se como sacarlo, ya probe con flexbox y con grid, pero siempre pasa lo mismo.

Si bien pude "ajustar" para que quede bien no es la forma, ya que por cada div tuve que modificar el alto, el top, aplicar posicion relativa y absoluta y me queda un relleno de atributos.
Como puedo evitar este efecto? yo quiero que mi segundo div quede puesto debajo del primer div "panel-lateralIzquierdo" y tambien debajo del after de este primer div.

```css
.panel-lateralIzquierdo {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  width: 21%;
  box-shadow: -6px 0 22px -6px #4f9;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.209);
}

.panel-lateralIzquierdo .operar-tareas {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
  top: 9%;
}

.panel-lateralIzquierdo .operar-tareas::before,
.operar-tareas::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
  width: 80%;
  height: 0.1%;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 22px 1px white;
}

.panel-lateralIzquierdo .operar-tareas::before {
  top: 0;
}

.panel-lateralIzquierdo .operar-tareas::after {
  bottom: 0;
}

.panel-lateralIzquierdo .cambiar-operacion {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 11%;
  top: 9%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor-general">

  <div class="panel-lateralIzquierdo">
    <div class="operar-tareas"></div>
    <div class="cambiar-operacion"></div>
  </div>

  <!-- ... Aqui hay otro div pero no aporta nada al caso -->
</div>
```

Comment: Hola Alan, no logro reproducir el problema que planteas. ¿Podrás [edit] tu pregunta agregar un [mcve]?

Comment: `cambiar-operacion` está dentro de `panel-lateralIzquierdo`, no puede quedar fuera

Comment: No, entendieron mal, ustedes tienen el panel izquierdo el cual contiene 2 divs. Ahora, al aplicar un after al primer div, el segundo queda entre en medio del primer div y el after del mismo primer div. No queda fuera del panel, si no que queda mal posicionado tomando el ::after el lugar que deberia ocupar el segundo div que es cambiar-operacion.

Comment: @AlanStone, yo no logro reproducirlo. Dentro del `div.cambiar-operacion` pongo texto y dentro del `.operar-tareas::after` y veo que esta por arriba. [Ejemplo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLqq3.png)